# Can't import python modules

Tags: python, easygui

I am trying to install EasyGUI. There is no `setup.py` so I can't install the module like you can with a proper module that has a `setup.py` file
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: After ten seconds of searching, I even located a video about how to install EasyGUI. What's your problem?

Comment: how about some specifics. Operating system, python version.

Comment: I have reasearched and still havent found a solution. I have followed videos but it still is not working

Comment: A small amount of research (ie "I typed `pip search easygui` into my terminal") suggests that you can install it with pip. I'd recommend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't install them, you just have to put it a directory, where Python find them, e.g. in a folder is already in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Perhaps the best if you put `PythonXX/Lib/site-packages` directory.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I installed a fresh copy of Python 2.7 and then it created a directory for Python. Moved the module into there and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Don't put manually python file into `PythonXX/Lib/site-packages` directory, use `pip install <package-name>` instead e.g.:

```
$ pip install easygui
```

The advantage is that you can upgrade it later:

```
$ pip install -U easygui
```

Or uninstall:

```
$ pip uninstall -U easygui
```

[pip is the preferred installer program.](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/)